# Why won't my flask command work on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, flask

I have a simple CLI took in Flask that I use to create dummy data. It works fine on my local machine but not on Heroku. Here's a terminal session:

```
(venv) $ flask create-dummy-data
(venv) $ git push staging master
Everything up-to-date
(venv) $ heroku run bash --remote staging
Running bash on ⬢ app-name... up, run.8533 (Free)
~ $ flask create-dummy-data
Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try "flask --help" for help.

Error: No such command "create-dummy-data".
```

Here's my `app/cli.py` file:

```
import lorem

from app import db
from app.models import Survey, Question, Option, Answer, Response

def register(app):
    @app.cli.command()
    def create_dummy_data():
        """Create lorem ipsum questions and answers for testing."""
        survey = Survey()
        db.session.add(survey)

        for _ in range(3):
            question = Question(survey=survey, category='likert', question=lorem.sentence())
            db.session.add(question)

        for _ in range (2):
            question = Question(survey=survey, category='word', question=lorem.sentence())
            db.session.add(question)

        db.session.commit()
```

And my `run.py` file:

```
from app import create_app, db, cli
from app.models import Survey, Question, Option, Answer, Response

app = create_app()
cli.register(app)

@app.shell_context_processor
def make_shell_context():
    return {'db': db,
            'Survey': Survey,
            'Question': Question,
            'Option': Option,
            'Answer': Answer,
            'Response': Response
            }
```

Why would this work locally but not on the Heroku shell?

Comment: Are you sure the file where you define `create-dummy-data` is committed?

Comment: @Chris, I wouldn't have thought of that, but I did just double-check and it is.

Comment: Does `heroku run flask create_dummy_data` work (using underscores instead of dashes)?

Comment: Neither `heroku run flask create_dummy_data --remote staging` nor `heroku run bash --remote staging` followed by `flask create_dummy_data` work.

Comment: And why is your function defined inside another function called `register`? I'm not super familiar with custom Flask commands, but I don't see anything like that in [the documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/cli/).

Comment: @Chris I admit I'm new to this, but it's the technique from chapter 15 of Miguel Greenberg's "The Flask Mega-Tutorial". I believe the reasoning is that using an app factory, as this does, means I can't simply import `app`, I have to create it first, and once it's created, I can then register the commands.

Comment: Are your dependencies tightly defined, with exact version numbers? Either by including them in `requirements.txt` using `==` or via a `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: I use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` each time I add a module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the simplest thing: Heroku didn't have `$FLASK_APP` set in the staging environment's variables. Adding that allowed the command line tool to run.

[image]